# formula manipulation in with quadratic form

Tags: r, math, machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence

I have a short question, why does the manipulation below does not work:

```
BAD ~ A + B + C # normal case

BAD ~ A + B^2 + C^2 # manipulated
```

what is the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R formula interface is not designed for symbolic mathematics but rather for modeling. If you want quadratic terms in your model then learn to use `poly`.

```
BAD ~ A + poly(B, 2) + poly(C,2)
```

Resist the temptation to se `I(C^2)` since this will deliver poor statistical inference. There are a couple of packages for symbolic manipulation of "equations": `polynom` is the name I remember off the top of my head. There is also the `RYacas` wrapper to the external symbolic math package Yacas.

If you were starting out with character values for the model components then this would assemble the pieces as text and finally convert to formula class:

```
> y = "Y"
> preds <- LETTERS[1:3]

> as.formula( paste( y,"~", paste( paste0( "poly(",preds,",",2, ")"), collapse="+") ))
Y ~ poly(A, 2) + poly(B, 2) + poly(C, 2)
```

I stumbled badly in trying to take a "two-sided" formula and `polyize` it. Maybe I'll ask that question myself.

Comment: thank you! is that possible to integrate it to the formula, like this: 

`form1 <- as.formula("BAD ~ A + B")
form2 <- poly(form1)`

to get:

`BAD ~ poly(A, 2) + poly(B, 2)`

I am trying to find a work around, but still without success, I have had a look at `polynom` package.

Comment: The first argument to `poly` needs to be either a name of an object in the evaluation environment that can deliver a numeric vector or be such a vector. I think you need to set up what might be called a programming use case. It's not clear at the moment where this expression is coming from and what is needed as the result.